# GeoServer: wrap data around the globe

Tags: geoserver

I think my problem is related to [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/85188/openlayers-and-geoserver-wmsgetfeatureinfo-does-not-return-feature-beyond-wrapd?rq=1) and [that question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7064/the-international-date-line-wrap-around).

I have some big raster layers on my GeoServer (v2.11.2) which span the whole world. They are organized in a Group Layer, where each (sub)continent makes up for one single layer.

On startup, the map is zoomed to the maximum extent and shows everything perfectly fine, but when I pan the map until the dateline comes into sight, the data beyond disappears, meaning the data itself is not wrapped around the world, while the basemap is. How can I fix this?

- Map Projection: Pseudo Mercator (EPSG: 3857)
- Data Projection: Pseudo Mercator (EPSG: 3857)
- Bounding Box set from layer bounds (using CRS bounds does not change the results)

Comment: please add some more details, what projection is your data in? what projection is your map in? what are the errors in the log file when you have turned on developer logging in global settings?

Comment: There has been done much work on the advanced projection handling in GeoServer very recently. Upgrade to [2.11.2](http://geoserver.org/release/stable/) and see if the problem still exists. Also have a look on the "[Projection handling options](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/webadmin.html#advanced-projection-handling-and-map-wrapping)" in the WMS settings.

Comment: @RoVo Thanks, but upgrading is not an option at the moment. We might try this some time in the future, but righ tnow we need a solution for this specific version.

Comment: I had this problem too and I doubt there will be a solution in 2.10.

Comment: Could you fix this with the newer version?

Comment: Not 100% sure about the current status. But we had the discussion on this bug and the [Release Announcement](http://blog.geoserver.org/2017/07/31/geoserver-2-11-2-released/) says: `Various raster improvements, including better handling of heterogeneous CRS mosaics`. You could try on a separate installation if you cannot upgrade.

Comment: Upgrade did not solve the issue. Edited question accordingly.